# Update Standard Salesforce Error Message

Tags: lookup, error

Can the standard error message for a lookup field be updated?

Error: Multiple items found. Select from drop-down or click icon to refine search.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter this error message, nor can you edit most of the standard error messages.

Comment: Not even via the Translation Workbench?

Comment: @KeithC Not even via TW. There's several Ideas out there about allowing this feature, but it doesn't exist yet.